# RPy2 robjects.r.pie gives curious error "'x' values must be positive"

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm feeling awfully silly, but I can't seem to work this out. I'm trying to make a pie chart, using rpy2 in Python.

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
import os.path

image = "test.png"
values = [0.5, 0.5]

print "using R"
r.png(image, width=100, height=100)
r.pie(values)
r.dev_off()
```

Now, to do the same thing directly in R I know I want this:

```
values <- (0.5, 0.5)
pie(values)
```

That works fine in the R interpreter. I've tried using tuples instead of lists in Python, but was told `ValueError: Nothing can be done for the type <type 'tuple'> at the moment.`

What Python type corresponds to the R vector? Do I need to use numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[note: your R code does not appear correct. You probably mean

```
values <- c(0.5, 0.5)
```

The use of the function *c()* matters; see below]

Currently rpy2 does not try to guess how one wants to represent in R a Python list or tuple.
This can be found in the rpy2 documentation.

Use either the R function *c()* or the rpy2 class *FloatVector*.

Comment: ... I've been working in Python too long. I forgot about types. o.O

Comment: Even in Python, when working with numerical data they are never too far. There are types with numpy too.